# How to write formula language in sharepoint 2010 for validating number column to european format

Tags: sharepoint-2010, formula

I have column called Indexation perunage. I need a validation message to be displayed if user tries to enter number in English format ( For eg : 1.25) it should accept numbers only in European format ( 1,25) – Shortly it should be validated not to allow decimal points

Comment: As you don't appear to have asked a question; good luck in your endeavor. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @andrew stubbs IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".";[INDEXATIONPERUNAGE]),"Accepts only european format",""))

Comment: Why don't you just change the currency format of the column?

Answer (score 0):

Change to Datasheet view on your site, click on the column header to highlight the column and then right click, select "Edit/Delete column.." You'll be able to select what type of currency format that you want.